# Where can I find a good ayin?

Tags: packages, characters, extended-characters

"Egyptological ayin" is a letter used in transcribing Ancient Egyptian, and looks sort of like a cross between a C and a left-quote. (In particular, it tends to be raised a bit above the baseline, and the bottom part of the curve is shorter than the top, unlike C.)

Does any package provide a good ayin that harmonizes with the standard LaTeX fonts (Computer Modern/Latin Modern/etc)? I know I can switch to a font like Noto (which I used for the example below) but it would be nice if someone had designed an ayin that fit in well with the rest of the letters.

(C on the left, ayin on the right.)
[image: comparison of C and ayin]

Comment: Problem solved? If yes, accept the answer :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `albatross "0xA725"` displays a list of all the fonts you have installed that support ꜥ (U+A725).  Ones that ship with TeX include Charis SIL, Doulos SIL, Gentium Plus, and DejaVu Sans.  Junicode has identical gylphs for the minescule and majescule, and you say you have already tried Noto.

Of these, I think Doulos SIL matches Computer Modern the best:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2 % Warn if the current font lacks a character!
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newfontfamily\egyptologyfont{Doulos SIL}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\newcommand\ayin{{\egyptologyfont\symbol{"A725}}}
\newcommand\Ayin{{\egyptologyfont\symbol{"A724}}}
\newunicodechar{^^^^a725}{\ayin} % Ꜥ
\newunicodechar{^^^^a724}{\Ayin} % ꜥ

\begin{document}
C c {\Ayin} {\ayin} Ꜥ ꜥ r
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern + Doulos SIL sample]